# Is it possible determining the sessionFactory on controller level using Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I'm using multiple `sessionfactory` for master/slave database connection.
BTW, is it possible determining the sessionfactory which I use on controller level with some what custom annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Qualifier` on the `SessionFactory` injection to delineate which one you want to use.  Example for setter-based injection to an `@Repository` DAO:

```
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("masterSessionFactory")
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```